# Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.6 does not start

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, percona, xtradb

All the good days. I want to run for test purposes Percona XtraDb Cluster on ubuntu 14.04. The basis here took these two articles

1. https://habrahabr.ru/post/152969/
2. https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/manual/bootstrap.html

I came instead

> Ну и в завершение, перезапускаем демона:

The daemon does not start

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start  
 * Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) database server mysqld 
 * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.pid).
   ...fail!
```

The logs several errors. Error one:

> [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

Sure I ran `mysql_upgrade`, but it does not work

> $ sudo mysql_upgrade
>   Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
>   FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Error two:

> 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>   160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE
>   ENGINE failed. 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage
>   engine: InnoDB 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Aborting

All are advised to remove all of the folders `/ var / lib / mysql` and supposedly starts. But I deleted and nothing worked.

My file my.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
# wsrep_urls=gcomm://192.168.33.101:3400,gcomm://192.168.33.102:3400,gcomm://
#wsrep_urls=gcomm://192.168.33.101:3400,gcomm://

[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size=256M
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.33.101
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
basedir=/usr
user=mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql.err
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_receive_address=192.168.33.101:3500
wsrep_node_incoming_address=192.168.33.101
wsrep_slave_threads=2
wsrep_cluster_name=cluster0
wsrep_provider_options="gmcast.listen_addr=tcp://192.168.33.101:3400;"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth=backup:password
wsrep_node_name=node0
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5000M
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M

[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Actually the question:** how to start? If there is anyone working configuration, then please share.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:
Percona is amazing, but highly undocumented.

When it comes to configuring it, ive learned less is better.
important parts:

```
server-id required
```

these may be braking it, in my experience.

```
wsrep_sst_receive_address=192.168.33.101:3500
wsrep_node_incoming_address=192.168.33.101
```

Config from my cluster:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=18
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so

# Cluster connection URL    -|-node0,    -|-node1,    -|-node2     -|-node3     -|-node4     -|-node5     -|-node6     -|-node7     -|-node8
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.1.18,192.168.1.19,192.168.1.20 #removed some

binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth="root:password"
wsrep_cluster_name=grapes

innodb_buffer_pool_size=5140
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
query_cache_size=0
```

Comment: Note innodb_buffer_pool_size=5140
equals 5.1gb of ram dedicated